# QGIS Download File Algorithm Ignore SSL Errors

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, download, ssl

I am requesting QGIS to download a file using Download File Algorithm in a pyqgis script. The URL is as follows `https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/mrlc_display/NLCD_2016_Impervious_L48/ows?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&layers=NLCD_2016_Impervious_L48&styles&crs=EPSG:3857&format=image/geotiff&request=GetMap&width=421&height=261&BBOX=-11698584.467247624,4925812.478408471,-11685967.801238675,4933631.516008289&`

**Note**

```
This URL is working on off, but the issue can still be tested on https://wrong.host.badssl.com/
```

The QGIS is throwing up this error and once I save SSL exception by doing Save&Ignore option. This window will not pop up but the algorithm will still fail.

[image]

I checked trough the browser and there is a certificate issue on the website but I can ignore it and proceed forward.

[image]

How can I request qgis file downloader to ignore this error? Here is my code:

```
    alg_params = {
    "URL": request_URL,
    "OUTPUT": QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
}
outputs["DownloadNlcdImp"] = processing.run(
    "native:filedownloader",
    alg_params,
    context=context,
    feedback=feedback,
    is_child_algorithm=True,
)
```

Comment: use GetCapabilities works in QGIS 3.18 https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/mrlc_display/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: @Mapperz can you explain this a bit more? I want to have it as a Layer ... because later on in my script I am vectorizing it and then doing GeoSpatial operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that this is a bug in QGIS. Bug tracker here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41846